# Is it safe if the client id and code verifier gets exposed?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, expo, pkce, expo-auth-session

I am using expo Auth-session for user login from my website using oauth2. When someone clicks on login button, it opens up the login page of my website with this url:

https://app.mywebsite.com/user/login?destination=/oauth/authorize%3Fclient_id%3D67gfet6uppWk%26code_challenge%3EMGrxQ_T6XvEgI0UMB3_3lmgdJ24ffe99yds%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26redirect_uri%3Dmyapp://Login%26response_type%3Dcode%26state%3DWFC075th

All the data like client id, code challenge etc. gets exposed in the url. Won't it be unsafe even if usePKCE is enabled as the code verifier is exposed during the authentication process?
Also, client secret is not used in this as it uses PKCE.

How can I hide these information from the URL during authentication?